# Help with evaluating Fourier transform of triangle wave

Tags: fourier-transform

I am told that I need to evaluate and sketch the Fourier transform of a triangle wave, shown below.

[image]

And I am given that the Fourier transform formula is given generally by

$$F(u) =  \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(x)e^{-iux}dx$$

where $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$ and $i = \sqrt-1$.

However, I am flummoxed as to how I am supposed to proceed with this problem and would appreciate any hints/suggestions. I guess I'm primarily confused because I don't understand how to proceed when I'm not given a formula for $f(x)$ that I can plug into my formula for $F(u)$. Do I need to find a formula for $f(x)$ within each period of the function?

Comment: Yes. It looks like the period is $2$, so you only need to define the wave on $[0,2]$.  It looks like $f(x) = 2x,$ then $f(x) = 2-2x$, then $f(x) = 2x-4$.

Comment: Be careful!  You need to calculate it as a tempered distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider cutting your graph into 6 pieces:

- $[0,   1/2]$
- $[1/2, 3/2]$
- $[3/2, 5/2]$
- $[5/2, 7/2]$
- $[7/2, 9/2]$
- $[9/2, 5]$

On each of the intervals, $f(x)$ is just a line. Can you find the equations and integrate?

Since this triangular wave is also periodic, can you use this to reduce the number of intervals needed?

Comment: When I integrate, will I keep positive and negative infinity as my bounds, or will I need to change it based on my interval? (i.e. if I'm integrating in the $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}$ interval, will those need to be my integral bounds?)

Comment: @maths yes, need to change the bounds...